# Access data in vba from report's query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm generating some reports with ms-access through a query, so I affect my recordSource of my report with my query.
But there is a way to access a field of the query by using vba ?
I want to affect a field in a variable once the report is generated but I don't know how to do that. I tried the following code but I got an error.

```
Dim rsFields As DAO.Recordset
Set rsFields = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Reports(NomRpt).RecordSource)
Debug.Print rsFields.Fields.Count
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: _affect a field in a variable once the report is generated_ ..? You should describe in common words what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm generating a report with data from a query, this query is affected as RecordSource of the report. But my question his, once generated, can we access to the result of the query through vba ?

Comment: By result of the query, do you mean the values outputed/shown in the report? If Yes. then its possible, but it depends on what you want to do with the output.  More clarification is needed

Comment: Yes exactly, the values shown in the report, I just want to store one value of the result query into a variable, I'm testing something for another problem I posted yesterday. I don't know if it's clear enough for you, but it's exactly what I want to do, I don't know how to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

It could be like:

```vb
Public Function ReadField()

    Dim Value   As Variant
    
    Dim rsFields As DAO.Recordset
    Set rsFields = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Reports(nomRpt).RecordSource)
    
    Value = rsFields.Fields(nomFld).Value
    
    Debug.Print rsFields.Fields.Count, Value
    
    rsFields.Close

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the following error : "Object variable or With block variable not set" 

Comment: You have to set your values of `nomRpt` and `nomFld`. Code runs nicely here.

Comment: I have set `nomFld`  with the field I want but still get the error

Comment: Can't tell. You must debug your data as the code is OK.

Comment: I wan't to understand something, this code open again the request ? because for this request I need one parameter and when I execute this code I get this error : "Not enough parameter, 1 expected"

Comment: This means, that a field or table name is either misspelled or missing.

Comment: Oh ok it's what I'm thinking, your solution need a table of the DB in parameter, but I just want to store in a variable the result of a specific field of the query, for example one of the field I want to retrieve is called "ref6", I don't want to retrieve the table "vquot" from where my field is stored. There is a simply way to get just my ref6 field from the report's query ? Or maybe I don't understand very well you're explanation. I'm not very familiar with vba and particularly Access

Comment: Only if the query returns two (or more) fields named "ref6", these will be prefixed with their table names.

Comment: Ok I found what I'm looking for with that : `Dim varX As Variant
    varX = DLookup("[ref6]", nameQuery)` but it works only for the first page, I have an error when I try to generate the other pages

Comment: `DLookup` just picks "the first the best" hit. Apply a filter to look up other records.